# Secure URL Schema communication

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, url-scheme

I want to have communication between two apps using url schema.

**I want to know what should I take care so that any other third party app does not try to represent my either of the app.**

Eg. A communicates with B and vice-versa.
if C tries to communicate with B representing as to be A OR
if C tries to communicate with A representing as to be B

Comment: You may take a look into wiki "[HTTP Secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)" (https). https and authentication is supported by iOS through various system libraries.

Comment: I want to secure access between two apps sharing data via url scheme... how would https came into picture and help me..
which library do you think suits for my requirement?

Comment: Ah, you refer to "iOS Custom URL Schemes"! "Custom URL Schemes" are less for sharing data between apps, but rather calling a service which  is executed by the target app. The target app registers for a particular custom URL scheme. _Any_ another app may call for that service by constructing an appropriate URL. The system then passes this URL to the app that registered for this URL. The service app MUST handle the URL in a delegate (of course it may ignore it, too - but that would be a questionable behavior for a service)

Comment: See also: [Validating Input and Interprocess Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/ValidatingInput.html)

Comment: above helps me.. Thanks

Comment: Another idea: if you want something like "authentication" - you may consider to incorporate a signed message in the query param of the URL. There are a few approaches how to accomplish this, basically the same underlaying techniques used in https. What you _need_ to do also depends on the kind of "attacks" - and whether this justifies the effort to make something secure. Note also, you never reach 100% security.